# How to save changed Divs (live)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so I've done some research and I haven't found anything about this for some reason, but I'll get to the point.

So what I'm trying to do is basically have a "webpage" that when opened (First time) has a `<button>` that is blue, but when clicked changes to red, but when you refresh/re-open the "webpage", it will stay Red (As in it auto-saved).

How can this be done?

Comment: css's :vistited selector can be a help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the off chance you are building a client-side only solution (just HTML/JS, loaded into a browser locally), you can use `localStorage`, or preserve the state in a cookie.

Most probably, you use a server to render the page. In which case, you'll want to save state changes in your database, and use it upon page re-renders ("refresh").